# R: surprising behaviour of `identical`

Tags: r

In R, I stumbled upon this surprising behaviour of the function `identical()`.

With simple `==`:

```
(ncol(dpx)-1) == length(test)
```

> TRUE

But with `identical`:

```
identical((ncol(dpx)-1) , length(test))
```

> FALSE

They are both of type integer (81 each).

What is happening?

Comment: My guess is that `class((ncol(dpx)-1))` returns "numeric", that's what `-` returns; while `length` returns an "integer".

Comment: Ah, correct! Is the `-1` changing the class to "numeric"?

Comment: I see. Also good to know `==` does not compare classes while `identical` seems to. Happy to tick it as answer if you write it.

Comment: small addition: if you define 1 as integer, then the answer will be identical. e.g. `class(ncol(dpx) - as.integer(1)) == length(test)` should return `TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`identical` is the "safe and reliable way to test two objects for being *exactly* equal." `ncol(dpx) - 1` returns a numeric vector due to `1` being numeric, while length returns an integer.

As pointed out by @amatsuo_net we could change the code slightly and convert the `1` to be of type integer.

```
identical((ncol(iris) + 1L - 1L), length(iris))
# [1] TRUE
```